# Querying an XML file using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, filtering

I have an `.xml` file which has an accompanying `.xsl` file. The output of which can be [found here](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~dtrunl01/podcatalog.xml).

I am attempting to have a html webpage where the user will be able to type into a search box, for example `'Year < 2009'`. And it will show the table found above but only where the Year is less than 2009.

I don't really have much idea where to start, or what I need to look into to create this functionality.

For reference, here's an XML snippet:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="podcatalog.xsl"?>
<pods-papers>
  <inproceedings key="AbbadiSC85">
    <crossref>conf/pods/85</crossref>
    <author>Amr El Abbadi</author>,
    <author>Dale Skeen</author>,
    <author>Flaviu Cristian</author>,
    <title>An Efficient, Fault-Tolerant Protocol for Replicated Data Management.</title>,
    <pages>215-229</pages>,
    <year>1985</year>,
    <booktitle>PODS</booktitle>,
  </inproceedings>
  <inproceedings key="AbbadiT86">
    <crossref>conf/pods/86</crossref>
    <author>Amr El Abbadi</author>,
    <author>Sam Toueg</author>,
    <title>Availability in Partitioned Replicated Databases.</title>,
    <pages>240-251</pages>,
    <year>1986</year>,
    <booktitle>PODS</booktitle>,
  </inproceedings>
  <inproceedings key="Abdel-GhaffarA90">
    <crossref>conf/pods/90</crossref>
    <author>Khaled A. S. Abdel-Ghaffar</author>,
    <author>Amr El Abbadi</author>,
    <title>On the Optimality of Disk Allocation for Cartesian Product Files.</title>,
    <pages>258-264</pages>,
    <year>1990</year>,
    <booktitle>PODS</booktitle>,
  </inproceedings>
  <inproceedings key="Abiteboul83">
    <crossref>conf/pods/83</crossref>
    <author>Serge Abiteboul</author>,
    <title>Disaggregations in Databases.</title>,
    <pages>384-388</pages>,
    <year>1983</year>,
    <booktitle>PODS</booktitle>,
  </inproceedings>
</pods-papers>
```

and here's the XSLT (`"podcatalog.xsl"`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Pods Papers</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9ACD32">
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="pods-papers/inproceedings">
    <xsl:sort select="author"/>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="pages"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note: ***I am not necessarily looking for the code, or what to write, but, for example, a web page that shows me how to implement all or parts of this***

Comment: I've added your XML/XLT for future reference. That page you link to might not be there forever, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

Add two script elements to your XSLT that will show up in the resulting HTML. The first will be jQuery (the Google-hosted version, for convenience):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the second manipulates your result table:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
$(function () {
  var filters = {};
  filters.run = function () {
    var i, $th = $("th"), $td, value;

    $("table tr:not(:visible)").show(); // clear any previously hidden rows

    for (var i=0; i<$th.length; i++) {  // for each filter string...
      if (this[i] > "") {
        $td = $th.eq(i).closest("table").find("tr:visible td:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");

        switch (this[i].slice(0,1)) { // first character is the operator
          case "<":
            value = $.trim( this[i].slice(1).toLowerCase() );
            $td.filter(function () {
              return $.trim( $(this).text().toLowerCase() ) >= value;
            }).closest("tr:visible").hide();
            break;
          case ">":
            value = $.trim( this[i].slice(1).toLowerCase() );
            $td.filter(function () {
              return $.trim( $(this).text().toLowerCase() ) <= value;
            }).closest("tr:visible").hide();
            break;
          case "/":
            value = new RegExp( this[i].slice(1) );
            $td.filter(function () {
              return !value.test( $.trim( $(this).text() ) );
            }).closest("tr:visible").hide();
            break;
          case "=":
            value = $.trim( this[i].slice(1).toLowerCase() );
            $td.filter(function () {
              return $.trim( $(this).text().toLowerCase() ) != value;
            }).closest("tr:visible").hide();
            break;
          default:
            value = $.trim( this[i].toLowerCase() );
            $td.filter(function () {
              return $.trim( $(this).text().toLowerCase() ).indexOf(value) == -1;
            }).closest("tr:visible").hide();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $("th").each(function () {
    $(this).append("<input type='text'>");
  });

  $("th input").change(function () {
    var index = $(this).closest("th").prevAll("th").length;

    filters[index] = $.trim( $(this).val() );
    filters.run();
  });
});
]]></script>
```

Here's what this does:

1. It adds an `<input>` element to each `<th>`. This input serves as a filter box for that column.
2. It maintains a set of `filters`, one for each column index.
3. Whenever an input changes (the change event occurs when the field loses focus), it writes the field's value to the set of filters and runs the filter.
4. "Running the filter" means:

   1. It goes through each saved filter string, figures out which operator (if any) was used
   2. It finds all `<td>` elements in the affected column and compares them to the filter value.
   3. When the cell value does not match the filter, the associated `<tr>` is hidden.
   4. Repeat process for next column.

This process results in additive filters, i.e. you can narrow down your search, filtering each column individually.

The first character of the filter string is supposed to be the operator.

Supported operators are

- `<` (less than),
- `>` (greater than)
- `=` (exact equality)
- `/` (regular expression).
- Any other filter string is interpreted as "contains".
- Add more operators if you want.

All comparisons except regular expression are case-insensitive.

See it in action on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/wjDrr/1/embedded/result/

---

P.S.:

I know this basically solves your entire problem. You said you have no idea where to start, so I suppose you'll have a hard-enough time figuring out the code and further adapting it to your needs. :)

The above code lacks some elegance, it breaks as soon as there is more then *one* table on the page and it certainly can be optimized for speed. If you care, you can improve these things.

Comment: This is great. I will certainly have to edit it but it is great to work off of. As someone who has 0 experience with web work, please understand why I sound so simple here: how do I call this function?

Comment: You do not have to call it yourself. jQuery does that for you as soon as the page is ready. Just try it out. :)

Comment: No way, this is amazing. This really wasn't what I intended to create but I am going to have fun playing around with this.

Comment: @Dan Trunley: It sounded close enough for me. What *did* you want to create? (Or is it what you need, only not how you'd have done it?)

Comment: It doesn't matter how I do it, just as long as it does it. I found that this method was a lot better than what I intended. I intended to have a html page where they type in their search string, and it is applied to this table.

Comment: @Dan Trunley: This would actually have been more complicated, because it means you'd first have to implement some sort of filter string parser (it needs to understand what `Year < 2009` actually refers to and it must not break on nonsensical input). Writing a parser that works well is a complex task. However, breaking it up into multiple, dedicated input fields removes this requirement (and coincidentally is more intuitive/user friendly as well, at least I think so).

Comment: I think your option is much more user friendly. One thing I don't understand however, is the `=` option. To me the line says it should return where all are not equal to the value you enter because of the `!=`

Comment: also, is there any way to display this from within a html page?

Comment: @Dan Trunley: Yes, it finds all rows where the respective column value *doesn't match* the filter and hides them, hence the `!=`. What do you mean with "from within an HTML page?

Comment: I.e. the html page would display the xml table?

Comment: As in, the user enters XML, which is then rendered into a table, which is then made searchable this way? Certainly that's possible, but this is material for a different question. I'd suggest you start with figuring out the above until you're sufficiently confident with it. If you don't have much experience it will take a while anyway. :)

Comment: Hey Tomalak, I'm having a similar problem to the original one and I'm really stuck, but I can't use jquery or what you are using in that second sript of yours.Imagine I'm having the same xml and xsl files as the original user. How can I do it by using XPATH expressions in a javascript? I want to create an html file that will have on the top a form with fields for the user to input the above values (larger than, equal to etc..) and a submit button and then take all these values inserted from this from and evaluate/apply them using XPATH in some other jscript function and reproduce the table.

Comment: @user There is - at least currently - no consistent XPath support among browsers. What keeps you from using jQuery?

Comment: Because we haven't been taught that yet, we've been taught that we can modify a stylesheet that is being applied on an xml file through javascript inside an html file programatically using XSLT in order to perform the selections needed on the xml file and format the results on our html table . we can use DOM features like getattributename setattributename....etc as well... and I only need that to run on IE and Moz

Comment: @Tomalak "I intended to have a html page where they type in their search string, and it is applied to this table" this is what I have in mind basically, something that evaluates the user's input and then takes the values that we need out of that input and applies them on xpath expressions across our xml so that xsl is modified accordingly and the table refreshed and redisplayed accordingly once the "submit" button is hit by the user. But I'm lost!

Comment: @user This solution relies heavily on jQuery, it cannot be ported easily. jQuery itself is "only" a DOM wrapper. So all of this effectively *does* run on native DOM functions behind the scenes, but making it run without jQuery is quite a bit of work. I'm sorry, but I'm not going to invest that amount of time. ;)

Comment: @user Read the 6th comment (*"This would actually have been more complicated..."*) - this is the exact situation you are in. This "something" you have in mind that somehow evaluates the user's input and does the right thing actually is *a lot* more complicated than my solution above. You should aim lower.

Comment: Being a newbie I can't realize the level of complexity I'm asking for here so I'll trust and respect your experience in the field but I simply have to do it that way, acording to our teacher the code needed is actually not that big :). Oh well, back to  square one.. but thanks anyway!

Comment: @user: You can always ask a fresh question. Link back here if something like the above is what you want, so people can get an idea. Describe your requirements (and your data!) closely, show some effort from your end and someone will help you.

Comment: @Tomalak I tried that here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574923/modifying-stylesheet-in-html-with-javascript-in-order-to-view-xml-in-different-w but got no replies,maybe I was being too general I don't know.. thanks for trying to help me anyway! :)

Comment: @user: Ah, I've seen this one. I can tell you what's wrong with it. It's too long. Too much code. Much too specific. Give people a problem to solve, not piles of code to debug (nobody likes debugging tons of foreign code). Abstract your problem. Give well-formed, actual XML - not a vaguely described, incomplete sample copied from Internet Explorer that would not even parse. The problem itself might be interesting, the question can (must) be improved. Be concise. Provide code that works. Shave off anything that is not part of the problem. You might want to delete that question and start over.

Comment: @Tomalak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574923/how-to-pass-values-from-user-input-to-js-function-to-use-them-for-xml-parsing hope it's a bit more precise now, for starters at least..:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8606/discussion-between-user1073400-and-tomalak)